# Gta V escape paparazzi

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I drove pass the escape paparazzi event with Franklin, so I know that I hadn't done the event yet. But when i drive passed the same location with trevor the blue dot won't appear. What time does the event appear?

Comment: You mean the blue area to start the mission or the blue question mark on the map`?

Answer (score 1):

Those types of 'missions' are random and don't appear to be tracked, I've driven past that dozens of times and not seen it, but have done it twice now. I can tell you both times it was during the day at least.

Comment: I did it at night :)